# NativeScript Angular Error TS5060: Option 'paths' cannot be used without specifying '--baseUrl' option

Tags: angular, webpack, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

I have freshly installed Nativescript Angular project using:

```
ng new --collection=@nativescript/schematics my-mobile-app
```

command I get from [nativescript-schematics](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-schematics)

and right after the fresh installation I try it to run on android emulator.

```
tns run android
```

then I get this error during compiling:

```
Searching for devices...
Preparing project...
File change detected. Starting incremental webpack compilation...

webpack is watching the files…

Hash: c018afa003f9a5a7d1cd
Version: webpack 4.44.2
Time: 4451ms
Built at: 11/05/2020 1:54:33 PM
 3 assets
Entrypoint bundle = runtime.js vendor.js bundle.js
[./app.css] 1.05 KiB {bundle} [built]
[./main.ts] 1.13 KiB {bundle} [built]
[~/package.json] external "~/package.json" 42 bytes {bundle} [optional] [built]
    + 331 hidden modules

ERROR in error TS5060: Option 'paths' cannot be used without specifying '--baseUrl' option.
```

Answer (score 6):

I also got the same error.  The way I fixed it was to add `"baseUrl": ".",` to **tsconfig.json**

So your **tsconfig.json** it ends up looking like:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "ESNext",
    "target": "es2017",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "noEmitHelpers": true,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",          // add this line
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom",
      "es6"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "platforms"
  ]
}
```

BUT then the next error you might get is:

```
cp: no such file or directory: E:/NativeScript/my-app/App_Resources/Android/*
```

So to fix that I moved the **App_Resources** folder, which was in the **app** folder, up one level like:

- from `my-app/app/App_Resources`
- to `my-app/App_Resources`

Then it finally ran correctly!